# Flask app on heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

I have an issue making my flask app working on heroku.

I'm using a simple flask app along flask-sqlalchemy
I didin't find anything specific on my problem altough I think I understand but can't figure it out how to make it work.

Here is the requirements.txt content:

```
    alembic==0.9.2
    click==6.7
    Flask==0.12.2
    Flask-Migrate==2.0.4
    Flask-Script==2.0.5
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
    Flask-WTF==0.14.2
    gunicorn==19.7.1
    itsdangerous==0.24
    Jinja2==2.9.6
    Mako==1.0.6
    MarkupSafe==1.0
    python-dateutil==2.6.0
    python-editor==1.0.3
    six==1.10.0
    SQLAlchemy==1.1.10
    Werkzeug==0.12.2
    WTForms==2.1
```

Here is the Procfile content:

```
    web: gunicorn main:app
```

Here is the output of log files in heroku dashboard

```
    2017-06-03T06:59:24.005560+00:00 app[web.1]:     return __import__('MySQLdb')
    2017-06-03T06:59:24.005561+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
    2017-06-03T06:59:24.769740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-spire-85572.herokuapp.com request_id=965e64b9-20f0-4aa0-8a71-d564068a5c70 fwd="31.5.203.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=https
    2017-06-03T07:32:46.321187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2017-06-03T07:32:46.321726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.062599+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-03 07:32:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.062699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-03 07:32:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.063539+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-03 07:32:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.110825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-03 07:32:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.055557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2017-06-03T07:32:47.247466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you, that you haven't installed the `MySQLdb` module. Add it to your requirements.txt

Comment: Is not working to install it with pip inside env folder.